# Is there a way in Ext JS to tell if a component has a dynamic or static width?

Tags: extjs, resize, width

I am looking for a way to determine whether an Ext JS component has a dynamic width or a static width. For instance, if a textfield has a width config set to 50, the config will have a static width of 50 regardless of the parent container's width. If that same component has a flex of 1, the width of the component will instead resize based on the size of the parent container. At the same time, I know that the component's parent container layout also impacts the child component's width.

How do I determine whether or not a component's width will change as the parent container is resized?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get using [`initialConfig`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#property-initialConfig) of ExtJS components.

> **initialConfig** object passed to the constructor during Component creation.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2frn)**, I have created a demo using a `window` and `textfield`. I have implemented here a `resize` event on `window` and get the dynamic width of component. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('DemoModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: 'viewmodel.demomodel',
            data: {
                textFieldWidth: null,
                initialWidth: null
            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'DEMO',
            viewModel: {
                type: 'demomodel'
            },
            width: 400,
            minWidth: 400,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            bodyPadding: 10,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                width: 50,
                anchor: '100%',
                emptyText: 'Enter value here...',
                fieldLabel: 'Demo TEXT'
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'initial Width',
                bind: '{initialWidth}'
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Dyanamic Width',
                bind: '{textFieldWidth}'
            }],
            listeners: {
                resize: function (cmp) {
                    var viewModel = cmp.getViewModel(),
                        textfield = cmp.down('textfield');
                    viewModel.set({
                        textFieldWidth: textfield.getWidth(),
                        initialWidth: textfield.initialConfig.width
                    });
                }
            }
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, so you're saying get the initial value set for width and compare to the current existing width? Then, if they are the same, that would mean the width is static. 

In regards to this strategy, there is one scenario that I wonder how to handle. In your example, say the width of the window is 100 with an hbox layout. And, say textfield has a flex of 2 and the displayfields each have a flex of 1 (meaning textfield takes up 50 of the 100 pixels of the window). How would I tell whether the textfield has a dynamic width since the inititalConfig width would be equal to the current width?

Comment: You saying about static width not about flex. Whenever you set flex it will automatically width on basis of screen width. Can you please breif explain what do you want with an example?

Comment: Please visit the following fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fsf    In the example, flex and width is set. Flex ultimately determines the width of field1. Based on the strategy we've been discussing, I would assume that I can tell whether a component's width is unchanging by comparing the original width with the current width. However, how can I tell whether the component width is unchanging when the current width is equal to the original width, as is the case in the example?

Comment: So for you can set `minWidth:300` so it will not change when if width will <300

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Rather than trying to set a minimum width, I am looking to figure out how to determine whether a component's width will change or not change as the component's parent container is resized.